# Transforming annotated csv (influxdb) to normal csv file using python script

Tags: python, csv, influxdb, influxdb-python

I have a `CSV` file that was downloaded from `InfluxDB UI`. I want to extract useful data from the downloaded file. A snippet of the downloaded file is as follows:

```
#group  FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#datatype   string  long    dateTime:RFC3339    dateTime:RFC3339    dateTime:RFC3339    double  string  string  string  string  string
#default    mean                                        
    result  table   _start  _stop   _time   _value  _field  _measurement    smart_module    serial  type
        0   2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T08:20:00Z    0   sm_alarm    system_test 8   2.14301E+11 sm_extended
        0   2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T08:40:00Z    0   sm_alarm    system_test 8   2.14301E+11 sm_extended
        0   2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:00:00Z    0   sm_alarm    system_test 8   2.14301E+11 sm_extended
        0   2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z  0   sm_alarm    system_test 8   2.14301E+11 sm_extended
```

I'd like to have the output CSV as follows:

```
_time                   sm_alarm  next_column next_column ....... ...........
2023-03-29T08:41:15Z    0
```

Please note that `sm_alarm` is only one field among 9 others (that are under `_filed`).

I tried to do with the following script, but could not solve my problem.

```
import csv

# Specify the input and output file names
input_file = 'influx.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'

try:
    # Open the input file for reading
    with open(input_file, 'r') as csv_file:
        # Create a CSV reader object
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        # Skip the first row (header)
        next(csv_reader)

        # Open the output file for writing
        with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as output_csv:
            # Create a CSV writer object
            csv_writer = csv.writer(output_csv)

            # Write the header row
            csv_writer.writerow(['_time', '_field', '_value'])

            # Iterate over the input file and write the rows to the output file
            for row in csv_reader:
                # Check if the row is not empty
                if row:
                    # Split the fields
                    fields = row[0].split(',')

                    # Write the row to the output file
                    csv_writer.writerow(fields)

    print(f'{input_file} converted to {output_file} successfully!')

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'Error: File {input_file} not found.')

except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error: {e}')
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are 11 headers and 10 values. It seems either the result or table value is missing from each row.

Answer (score 1):

The format of your expected output is ambiguous and not fully clear.
But as a *starting point*, you can straighten your file with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) this way  :

```
import pandas as pd
​
with open("influx.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    headers = csv_file.readlines()[3].strip().split()[1:]
    
df = pd.read_csv("influx.csv", header=None, skiprows=4, sep="\s+",
                 engine="python", names=headers).iloc[:, 1:]

#df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, sep=",") # <- uncomment this line to make a real csv
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                           _start                           _stop                           _time  _value    _field _measurement  smart_module        serial         type
0  2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z            2023-03-31T08:20:00Z       0  sm_alarm  system_test             8  2.143010e+11  sm_extended
1  2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z            2023-03-31T08:40:00Z       0  sm_alarm  system_test             8  2.143010e+11  sm_extended
2  2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z            2023-03-31T09:00:00Z       0  sm_alarm  system_test             8  2.143010e+11  sm_extended
3  2023-03-31T08:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z  2023-03-31T09:12:40.697076925Z       0  sm_alarm  system_test             8  2.143010e+11  sm_extended
```

*If you share a clear expected ouptut, I'll update my answer accordingly.*